# Unable to append an image to d3 svg element

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, d3.js, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am working on a power bi custom visual using d3 and typescript. I have declared my constructor as below:

```
constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
    this.host = options.host;

    // Declare the svg property
    this.svg = d3
      .select(options.element)
      .append("svg")
      .classed(Visual.ClassName, true);

    this.svg
      .append("svg:image")
      .attr(
        "xlink:href",
        "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png"
      )
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", 40)
      .attr("height", 40);
  }
```

But the thing is no actual image appears on canvas/svg. Only an image icon appears as shown below. What might be the issue and its solution.
And thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: SVG elemnts belongs to `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` name space, not to default HTML name space...

Comment: Is there any work around for it. I am using power bi services to host my visual.